# Touchpad scroll not working after an update

Tags: touchpad, drive, scrolling

I have updated ubuntu 14.04. Previously the touchpad scrolling worked but after updating, it doesn't work. I have tried several things but keep failing. Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulz8s.png)

I also have installed tweak tool but still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf` (if it exists)?

Comment: no it says no such file directory....